# How to "pip-upgrade" a (private) package from a VCS (git) repository?

Tags: pip, python-packaging

i've installed a private package with :

```
pip install git+https://gitlab.com/toto/titi.git@master
```

my private packge is:

```
└───titi
    │   README.md
    │   setup.py
    └───titi
            functions.py
            __init__.py
```

my setup.py before the upgrade was :

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="titi",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="toto",
    author_email="titi@gmail.com",
    description="pouet",
    long_description=long_description,
    url="+https://gitlab.com/toto/titi",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: raymond :: aron",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

i've changed things in my package and updated setup.py :

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="gitandpip",
    version="0.0.2",
    author="toto",
    author_email="titi@gmail.com",
    description="pouet",
    long_description=long_description,
    url="+https://gitlab.com/toto/titi",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: raymond :: aron",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

but when i do a :

```
pip install --upgrade titi
```

i have a :

```
Requirement already satisfied: titi in /home/toto/.local/share/virtualenvs/test_module-EH1iEwqJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)
```

How to upgrade my private package ?

I can do a

```
pip uninstall titi
```

then

```
pip install git+https://gitlab.com/toto/titi.git@master
```

But it's not elegant.

regards

Comment: Things that do not come from a package index (like PyPI and others), are always a bit tricky, the behavior is always different. In your case you might want to try `python -m pip install --ignore-installed ...`. Maybe you could also try `python -m pip install 'gitandpip>0.0.1 @ git+https://...'`, or probably it would be a good idea to use git tags (instead of `master`): `python -m pip install 'gitandpip @ git+https://gitlab.com/toto/titi.git@v0.0.2'`.